# Webview android não carrega imagem css

Tags: android, css, webview

Estou carregando uma página html com um css em uma webview, todos os arquivos são locais e estão na mesma pasta. Está funcionando normalmente em meu dispositivo Motorola Moto X 2 e no meu tablet Galaxy Tab 10, porém no Galaxy Tab 4 com a versão 4.4.2 a imagem não está sendo renderizada pelo css.

Comando que utilizo para carregar a página:

```
webView.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(index).toString());
```

Onde index é o arquivo index.html da pasta;

CSS que carrega a imagem:

```
.bt_play{background:url('ico_play.png') no-repeat right;   padding: 20px 75px 20px 5px!important; display:table; float: right;}
.bt_play p{font-size: 1.7em!important;}
```

Já utilizei de várias técnicas e códigos para fazer com que a imagem apareça neste tablet especifico, mas nada funciona...
Alguém tem idéia?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar a melhor performance do hardware com:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Ou no manifest colocar:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: obrigado, mas funcionou colocando android:hardwareAccelerated="true" no manifest.

Comment: Editei a resposta.